# angular js Bootstrap not working with multiple rows and columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am making a basic blackjack game with angularjs and using bootstrap for the layout however I cannot seem to make it work.
What I want is a heading across the top, the content of the game in the middle and left and a list of current players on the right but isn't everything is running down the page.
My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Blackjack</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="./angular.js"></script>
<script src="./angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="./angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="./ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="main">
<div class = "row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<h1>Black Jack</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class = "col-sm-10">
<div ng-include="'play.html'" my-replace>
</div>
<div ng-include="'next.html'" my-replace>
</div>
<div ng-include="'start.html'" my-replace>    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<ul class = "row">
<li class="col-sm-12">
<h2>Players</h2>
</li>
<li class = "col-sm-12" ng-repeat="player in players">
<span>{{player.name}}: <button ng-if="!started" ng-click='removePlayer(player)'>Remove</button></span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"> </script>
<script>
div = $("div");
(function add(div){
div.each(function(i, val){
this.innerHTML=this.nodeName+" open "+this.className+" "+this.innerHTML+" "+this . nodeName+" close"
add($(this).children());
})})(div);

</script>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

The my-replace directive strips away the wrapping div of the ng-includes once their content loads.
The js code at the bottom is a quick debugger so I can see how the html was being interpreted as firebug light doesn't work with angularjs.
I've tried with multiple versions of bootstrap too
Why isn't the bootstrap working?

Comment: ui-bootstrap was not written for bootstrap 4

Comment: I was originally using 3 but it had the same problem